# Disjoint union of topological spaces

Tags: general-topology, universal-property

I want to show that the union $\{0\}\cup(0,1)=[0,1)$ is not a disjoint union of topological spaces. It's my first time handling such a problem and I don't even know when is a topological space a disjoint union or not.  I tried referring to the Universal Property of disjoint union but couldn't see how it helps me. Any hint would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: In the disjoint union topology on $[0, 1)$ (using your sets), $\{0\}$ would be open. Can you prove that it is not open in the usual topology on $[0, 1)$? Moreover, could you prove that *no* singleton is open in $[0,1)$?

Comment: I know that  [0,1) is hausdorff, and therefore every finite set (hence every singleton) is a close set. What makes $\{0\}$ open in this case?

Comment: *A priori*, $\{0\}$ being closed has no bearing on whether or not it is open. However, $\mathbb{R}$ has some extra structure that would allow you to show that it's not open. Do you know the terms "connected" or "path connected"?

Comment: Yes I'm familiar with this terminology.

Comment: In that case: $[0, 1)$ is path connected (with the straight line path between any two points). Ergo, it is connected, so there does not exist any non-trivial clopen sets. $\{0\}$ is closed (your reasoning), so it cannot be open.